# Why I get now login prompt when I try to add new document or save as existing document?

Tags: 2010, document-library, sharepoint-server, login

I am using sp2010. When I try to add a new document in a library I got a login prompt. When I open an existing word document and click on save as I got also the login prompt.

Before I didnt got this behavior. How can I fix this?

Comment: is this new issue( means started in old enviroment), for one user or all users, any browser specific? check this link, it will fix the most of the prompt issue. http://www.networkadminsecrets.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-authentication-prompts.html

Comment: ok let me add this as answer so that other get benefits and i get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of issue when you get multiple login prompts when opening / adding documents usually can easily fix by adding the site in the Trusted zone.

To add site into Trusted zone Please follow instructions:

1. Add your site to the Trusted Sites Internet Zone.
2. Go to Internet Options - Security - Highlight the Trusted Sites
   Check Mark - click on custom level - scroll to the bottom and in the
   user authentication section select "Automatic logon with current
   username and password."
3. This can be done via group policy by going to:  User Configuration -
   Policies - Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Internet
   Explorer - Internet Control Panel - Security Page - Trusted Sites
   Zone. From here find "Logon Options" and enable it. Pick the
   "Automatic logon with current username and password option."

http://www.networkadminsecrets.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-authentication-prompts.html